# Inserting a variable into a list c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Basically this is my code in the datalayer. I am just having trouble with the second from last line of code. I am trying to insert the variable 'distinctIdsWoring' into the list promoCodeValues but i am getting an error.

```
    public static List<PromotionalCodeValue> GetPromotionalCodeValues(string Platform)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = xxxConnection();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("GetPromotionalCodeValues", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Platform", Platform);

        conn.Open();

        List<PromotionalCodeValue> promoCodeValues = new List<PromotionalCodeValue>();

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader dataReader = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                promoCodeValues.Add(new PromotionalCodeValue(dataReader));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        promoCodeValues.Clear();

        var distinctIdsWorking = promoCodeValues.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    id = s.Value,
                })
                .Distinct().ToList();

        promoCodeValues = distinctIdsWorking; //????????????????????????????

        return promoCodeValues;

    }
```

thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: please place `distinctIdsWorking` into backquotes and make it identic to variable in code and where is the error

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Error is:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonomousType#1>'to'System.Collections.Generic.List'<TestingApp.BE.PromotionalCodeValue>'

Comment: @TimSchmelter sos tim, was feeling a bit lucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`distinctIdsWorking` is not a  `List<PromotionalCodeValue>`, so you cannot assign it to `promoCodeValues`.

It looks like you're trying to ensure that you only get one promo code per ID in your results. Try something like this:

```
public static List<PromotionalCodeValue> GetPromotionalCodeValues(string Platform)
{
    // This ensures that your connection gets closed even if there's
    // an exception thrown. No need for a try/finally
    using (SqlConnection conn = xxxConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("GetPromotionalCodeValues", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Platform", Platform);

        conn.Open();

        List<PromotionalCodeValue> promoCodeValues = new List<PromotionalCodeValue>();

        SqlDataReader dataReader = comm.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            promoCodeValues.Add(new PromotionalCodeValue(dataReader));
        }

        promoCodeValues = 
            (from pc in promoCodeValues
            // Group by ID, then choose the first item from each group;
            // This is effectively the same as "DistinctBy" but requires
            // no extra methods or classes.
            group pc by pc.Value into g
            select g.First())
                .ToList();

        return promoCodeValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2991718: I updated my answer with some code to show how to fix this. Unlike most of the other answers here, it doesn't require you to add any new classes or methods.

Comment: YOU GUYS ARE ACTUALLY SO FANTASTIC. THIS ALSO WORKED. Stripling Warrior THANK YOU. I APPRECIATE IT.

Comment: @user2991718: I'm glad we were able to help. I suggest "Accepting" an answer, so that other users know that your problem was resolved. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning `distinctIdsWorking` to `promoCodeValues` which have incompatible types.

Instead try using the `IEqualityComparer` overload of [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx).

```
public class PromotionalCodeEqualityComparer
    : IEqualityComparer<PromotionalCodeValue>
{
    public bool Equals(PromotionalCodeValue x, PromotionalCodeValue y)
    {
        return x.Value == y.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(PromotionalCodeValue obj)
    {
        return obj.Value != null ? obj.Value.GetHashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var distinctIdsWorking = promoCodeValues.Distinct(new PromotionalCodeEqualityComparer());

return distinctIdsWorking;
```

You're also clearing the `promoCodeValues` which will return nothing and you're missing `using` statements.

Corrected:

```
var promoCodeValues = new List<PromotionalCodeValue>();

using(var connection = xxxConnection())
using(var command = new SqlCommand("GetPromotionalCodeValues", connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Platform", Platform);

    connection.Open();

    using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            promoCodeValues.Add(new PromotionalCodeValue(reader));
        }
    }
}

return promoCodeValues.Distinct(new PromotionalCodeEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: where do i put this class 'PromotionalCodeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<PromotionalCodeValue' ?

Comment: @user2991718, just build a new class file for it. It just needs to be accessible somewhere.

Comment: Yes inside Visual Studio right click a folder and click add -> class.

Comment: ROMOKU AND MICHEAL. LAWD HAVE MERCY ON YOU. THIS JUST WORKED. THANK YOU SO MUCH xxx

Answer (score 2):

You are clearing the list with `promoCodeValues.Clear();` so `distinctIdsWorking` is always an empty list with no elements in it.

Comment: the original list returns 180 results, i clear it because after the LINQ i only want the distinct values. not all of them

Comment: If I assume correctly. `Clear()` removes all elements from the List. The next line of code then tries to grab all distinct records from that list. Thus, distinctIdsWorking will be a list of distinct records of a list with 0 records in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help chris. Appreciate it x

Answer (score 1):

To simplify this, first build an equality comparer:

```
public class PromotionalCodeValueEqualityComparer :
    IEqualityComparer<PromotionalCodeValue>
{
    public bool Equals(PromotionalCodeValue x, PromotionalCodeValue y)
    {
        return x.Value == y.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(PromotionalCodeValue x)
    {
        return x.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and then you can just do this:

```
return promoCodeValues.Distinct(new PromotionalCodeValueEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me =(

Comment: thanks for your response, but you have suggested putting this class in. where do i actually put this class?

Comment: @user2991718, just add the class to the project. In other words, add a new class file named `PromotionalCodeValueEqualityComparer` through Visual Studio.

Comment: I am new to this, sorry for down voting if it was me. You guys helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A    var distinctIdsWorking = promoCodeValues.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        id = s.Value,
                    })
                    .Distinct().ToList();

Look carefully: via `Select(s => new { id = s.Value })` statement you generate anonymous object with only ID field, it is not the previous class (`PromotionalCodeValue`) after that.

All that your need is to install [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) package or take this code extension cutted from that framework:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

And use this: `DistinctBy(x => x.ID)` or if you need multiple keys: `DistinctBy(x => { x.ID, x.Name })`

So you can rewrite your code:
`var distinctIdsWorking = promoCodeValues.AsEnumerable().DistinctBy(code => code.Value).ToList();`

Comment: this code really helped. i get on error tho. i put the var distinctIdsWorking = promoCodeValues.DistinctBy(c => c.id).ToList(); inside my method but it says 'DistinctBy' cannot be found.

both methods are public tho

Comment: Add extension to public static class, add namespaces and references, try updated code. If you don't get success try call static method explicitly, like this `StaticClass.DistinctBy(promoCodeValues, code => code.Value).ToList()`

Comment: The solution was posted by someone, but thank you for you time as well.